# Access parent fields config properties from child class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, autowired

I have the following classes:

Parent.class

```
@Configuration
public class Parent{
    boolean foo;
}
```

Child.class

```
@Configuration
@Configuration(prefix = "text.prop")
public class Child extends Parent{
    int num;
}
```

Child2.class

```
@Configuration
@Configuration(prefix = "text.prop2")
public class Child2 extends Parent{
    int num;
}
```

application.yml:

```
text:
    prop:
        foo: true
        num: 67
    prop2:
        foo: false
        num: 67
```

when I'm auto-wiring the `Child.class`, the value of the field `foo` is not getting initialized from `application.yml`

Is there any better way to do this? or how can i access the field `foo` value when the spring initializes `Child.class`

Comment: Use Aggreagation instead of inheritance

Comment: how can I use aggregation here? I have different child classes with the same parent class. Ex: class A and Class B both are extending class C

Answer (score 0):

I did the following test and it looks it works:

```
public class Parent {
    private boolean foo;

    public boolean isFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public Parent setFoo(boolean foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        return this;
    }
}
```

and the child class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "text.prop")
public class Child extends Parent{
    private int num;

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public Child setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
        return this;
    }

    @Bean
    public String dummyBean(){
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println(isFoo());
        return "dummyBean";
    }
}
```

and for child2 we have:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "text.prop2")
public class Child2 extends Parent{
    private int num;

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public Child2 setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
        return this;
    }

    @Bean
    public String dummyBean2(){
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println(isFoo());
        return "dummyBean";
    }
}
```

the value printed in console:

```
67
true
67
false
```

If `Parent` class is a `@Configuration` class add `@AutoConfigureAfter(value = {Parent.class})` to child classes

Comment: it works because you have added 'text.prop' in parent class.

Comment: i have edited the question. It wont work if there are diff child classes

Comment: @vinter still not working ??

Comment: why are you returning Child type in the setter?

Comment: @vinter Actually  it is generated by IDE and here it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to define getters and setters in the parent class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).